# No puedo ver recurso cargado sin errores desde SVG

Tags: android-studio

He cargado un archivo .svg "a priori" sin ningún problema y lo encuentro cargado en la carpeta res/drawable.
Si accedo al mismo, puedo ver el código y su preview sin problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A pesar de esto, cuando trato de cagarla en la actividad, como imagen de un botón, no me aparece el recurso como disponible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Reinicia el android studio es un error que suele pasar, con el reinicio de aseguraras que tenga la nueva imagen cargada

Comment: Sí, evidentemente, reiniciar ya lo había descartado. No funcionó

Comment: Puedes mostar el arbol completo del proyecto a ver como lo tienes organizado puede que el problema vaya por ahi

Comment: Pues sí... va por ahí... Si te fijas el archivo lo ha creado android studio en la carpeta ../res/res/drawable/ No me queda claro, por qué lo ha creado en esa carpeta y si simplemente copiándolo a la carpeta donde deberían estar ../res/drawable/ Lo he copiado y así funciona.

Comment: Pues ya lo tienes no?

Comment: Eso parece... no sé si es lo más ortodoxo, pero funciona.

Comment: Es la forma de hacerlo que establece google si te saltas la nomenclatura las funciones para coger los recursos no te funcionaran

Comment: Lo extraño es que hice la carga desde android studio a través del resource manager, y lo creó esa ubicación extraña.

Answer (score 0):

Usando Android Studio para crear las imagenes en Android, el sistema había creado una carpeta dentro de /res llamada /res.drawable.

Es necesario que las imágenes se encuentren en /res/drawable y no en /res/res/drawable para que sean detectadas por el sistema.

He copiado los archivos a la carpeta /res/drawable y el sistema los ha detectado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]